# How to link a field from one model to a specific field of another model

Tags: django

So I have a platform class where I can set all platforms

library/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Platform(models.Model):
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.platform

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    reddit = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

then I have a model class where I can set the platforms for that game

and each game has its own posts. How do i set the platform field in the Post Model to inherit the platforms from the Game model. I'm doing this so I can sort the posts by the games specific platforms.

main/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from library.models import Game, Platform
from users.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from vote.models import VoteModel

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png', upload_to='article_pics')
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='platform')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_published"]


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

Before suggesting a solution, you need to understand that repeated fields means your models are not normalized. I suggest that you remove the field platform from Post, therefore your new model will be as follow :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png', upload_to='article_pics')
```

Now to sort Post based on platforms, you only need to use this ORM query :

```
posts_by_platforms = Post.objects.all().order_by(game__platform)
```

Or if you want to order them by platform and by date you can use this :

```
posts_by_platforms = Post.objects.all().order_by(-date_published, game__platform)
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know I could do it like that. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at this again it wont work for my specific problem. Each game has different platforms but each post under a game can only have one platform. If I use your method I believe all the platforms are inherited by a post.